# Access Service Endpoint After Authorization by Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I've developed a backend API and secured it with Keycloak. So, when accessing from the browser all works fine. However, I also want to use it as a backend service.
I got the access_token from the below endpoint, and it works fine. But when I access my application endpoint `http//localhost:8082/app/service/v1/ping` it gives me a login page in the postman response body.

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8083/os/realms/X/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: AUTH_SESSION_ID=3385934f-ee26-4c34-a588-797206075e82; AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=3385934f-ee26-4c34-a588-797206075e82' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=x-clientid' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=dXejmoCZcE3kfErlCUzlPKkDp6GnfPEY' \
--data-urlencode 'username=john@test.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=123'
```

Calling my app endpoint

```
curl --location 'http//localhost:8082/app/service/v1/ping' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ........9UlKWilg' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=241A3ABD96C958EAB3E4EB71BDF988FC'
```